# Are two intergers equal PHP/CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement

A very simple query that I cannot seem to figure out...

I'm using the CodeIgniter framework.

I'm retrieving data from my database and accessing the cols within the returned row via:

```
$item->available
```

where 'available' is the column of type int.

Now, I'd like to check whether the returned integer is 1 or not.

I believed this would be a simple case of

```
if ($item->available == 1) {
  echo "Available";
} else {
  echo "Sold";
}
}
```

However, this is not working. Can somebody please offer me some direction?

Comment: To debug, try `var_dump($item->available);`. That should tell you what `$available` is in PHP :) x

Comment: can you post the code where you retrieve data?

Comment: You have an extra `}` in your code.

Comment: @ Mike B - productive. Would you prefer 'non-functional', or 'f****d'. Comment noted.

Thanks for the other comments guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`==` will only equivelent, so `true == 1` `'1' == 1` etc..  to match type use `===` this will ensure only `(int)1 === (int)1`

And for consistancy, use type-casting to ensure type like so...

```
if ((int)$item->available === 1) {
  echo "Available";
} else {
  echo "Sold";
}
```

Comment: I don't know what case you're solving. Whatever available is (string 1 or int 1) should resolve to true regardless: http://codepad.org/ko4QI3Gw